# mvwaddstr() causes false positive with McAfee

Tags: c, ncurses, false-positive, pdcurses

I've been writing a C Curses application with PDCurses. It was compiling and running fine, but when I added some code to draw a string in a window, McAfee quarantines my compiled .exe as a trojan. Here is the line that causes the false positive:

```
mvwaddstr(window, 1, 1, "a string");
```

With this line commented, McAfee doesn't detect it as a trojan. With this line active, it does. It detects it as the trojan `GenericRXAM-FG!752E40763FE4`. Googling this gave me no results. Why is this happening? Is there a way I can have McAfee not quarantine this file?

Comment: McAfee looks at patterns (or just plain strings), and you got a false positive (i.e., probably a mistake).

Comment: Okay, but is there a way to have it ignore these patterns/this file?

Comment: As a bug-report - see their [knowledge base articles](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB85567)

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can create an exception to not scan that file into mcafee
just add the path to it, depends on which version of mcafee but to generalise something like :
1. Type “VirusScan Console” at the Start screen and press “Enter.” 2. Right-click “On-Access Scanner” listed in the left window pane and select “Properties.” 3. Click “All Processes, Detection, Exclusions” and select the “Exclusions” tab. 4. Click the “Add” button, click “Browse” and select the folder or file you want to add as an exception. 5. Click “OK” in the “Add Exclusions Item” dialog box and click “OK” in the “Set Exclusions” prompt. 6. Click “Apply” in the “On-Demand Scan Properties” window and click “OK” to save your settings.

Comment: It would be better if you explain how to do it.

Comment: 1.

Type “VirusScan Console” at the Start screen and press “Enter.”

2.

Right-click “On-Access Scanner” listed in the left window pane and select “Properties.”

3.

Click “All Processes, Detection, Exclusions” and select the “Exclusions” tab.

4.

Click the “Add” button, click “Browse” and select the folder or file you want to add as an exception.

5.

Click “OK” in the “Add Exclusions Item” dialog box and click “OK” in the “Set Exclusions” prompt.

6.

Click “Apply” in the “On-Demand Scan Properties” window and click “OK” to save your settings.

Comment: Add the explanation to your answer (not in the comment). Click on the `edit` option just under your answer.

Answer (score -1):

this is not universal, it depends on the mcafee version you are using, there are many, entreprise, security etc, menus are different... 
bu to generalise, hope is the good version: 1.

Type “VirusScan Console” at the Start screen and press “Enter.”

2.

Right-click “On-Access Scanner” listed in the left window pane and select “Properties.”

3.

Click “All Processes, Detection, Exclusions” and select the “Exclusions” tab.

4.

Click the “Add” button, click “Browse” and select the folder or file you want to add as an exception.

5.

Click “OK” in the “Add Exclusions Item” dialog box and click “OK” in the “Set Exclusions” prompt.

6.

Click “Apply” in the “On-Demand Scan Properties” window and click “OK” to save your settings.

Comment: You should merge this into your older answer.